# Allow only read/write of one child

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been messing around with my firebase database rules to try and allow users without authentication to only edit a certain child in my database, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is the database structure:

[image]

So I'm trying to allow users without authentication to edit the videoID, but not only that, I need the rule to ignore the room id (5555 in this example), meaning it only allows reading and editing of **rooms/(roomid)/videoID**

Thanks for all kinds of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Database rules allow variables and can have different rules at different depths.

In your case, the below rules would allow any users (authenticated or not) to access `/rooms/$roomid/videoID` but only authenticated users to access the entire `/rooms/` tree.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "rooms": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null",
      "$roomid": {
        "videoID": {
          ".read": "true",
          ".write": "true",
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The Firebase rule simulator (accessible from the Rules tab of the Firebase Database console) is useful for testing rules before publishing:
 [image: simulator]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this :

```
{
  "rules": {
     ".read": true,
     ".write": "auth != null",  
     "rooms": {
       "$roomId": {
           "videoID": {
             ".write": true
           }
       }
     }
  }
}
```

It will allow user with authentification to edit another field beside `videoID`.

But if you want even authentificated user, also can only edit `videoID`, then the rule is :

```
{
  "rules": {
     ".read": true,
     ".write": false,  
     "rooms": {
       "$roomId": {
           "videoID": {
             ".write": true
           }
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Remember, when the rule set `true` it will not traverse the child rule, But if it set `false` it will continue inspect the child rules.